# multiple UITextFields on one view

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I've got a little problem with uitextfield. I use two of them in a view and when I write something to the second field the first string gets changed too.
Here is my code

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

textString = textField.text;
NSLog(@"the string1 %@",textString);
[textField resignFirstResponder];


textString2 = textField2.text;
NSLog(@"the string2 %@",textString2);
[textField2 resignFirstResponder];

return YES;}
```

so I need some help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `textFieldShouldReturn` method gets called for both the fields so you need to distinguish between the actions for each field.

Set a tag to both the text fields:

```
myTextField1.tag = 100;
myTextField2.tag = 101;
```

and check for the tag in the `textFieldShouldReturn` method:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField.tag == 100)
    {
        textString = textField.text;
    }
    else if(textField.tag == 101)
    {
        textString2 = textField.text;
    }

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Here textField is the object passed to the delegate i'e' the one on which you have tapped return. So use that and not your IBOutlet object.

And please avoid naming your text fields textField and textField2 its a very bad coding practice.

Good Luck

Comment: well good that your problem is solved, but what i meant by bad coding practice is that your object names should be intuitive like 'userNameTextFiled', 'passwordTextFiled' etc. so that even is someone else looks at your code (or even if you see it after an year) they understand whats happening. so i would say naming it 'text' as you did isn't that great either.. sorry if i'm bugging you with the lecture though..

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your `IBOutlets` might be pointing to the same object.  Re-check your connections in Interface Builder.